# How to add footer template or editor template in MVC web grid ,

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

ASP.net Grid view allow us to have multiple templates like 
 for editing current row will be displayed as row of input fields
for adding new record , row of text boxes will appear in footer templates

How can acheive this in mvc Web Grid on click of add and Edit Button

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778455/abstract-should-i-choose-asp-net-mvc-over-web-forms-or

Comment: Thanks Omkar , but it is not related to question. I believe almost everything is possible in MVC and it provide a lot of benefits over web forms so not going back to ASP.NET web forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey This is what i used in my web grid. This might help You.

```
<h1>@Page.Title</h1>
<form method="post">
    @Html.DropDownList("OrderID", orders)
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

@if(grid != null){
    @grid.Table(
            columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("ProductName", "Product", style: "_220"),
                grid.Column("UnitPrice", "Price", style: "_60", format: @<text>@item.UnitPrice.ToString("c")</text>),
                grid.Column("Quantity", style: "_90"),
                grid.Column("TotalCost", "Total Cost", style: "_90", format: @<text>@item.TotalCost.ToString("c")</text>)
            ), 
            footer: @<table class="footer">
                         <tr>
                             <td class="_220">Total</td>
                             <td colspan="2" class="_150">&nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="_90">@orderTotal.ToString("c")</td>
                         </tr>
                    </table>);
}
```

Comment: Rajan , It looks like copy paste from other website . Also it does not solve the problem. Please correct me if i wrong ,this is a static look footer , not a dynamic like in asp.ner grid view. In this footer how can we bound model items , and what about edit template ?

Comment: There is a lot of JavaScript Code Wrote for that Dynamic Footer.